# AutoIncrement Issue : The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = UserId ]

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce, auto-increment

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC4 and trying to add a new entry to a table which has an `Integer` as primary key. I know about the identity issue and set it to true, I also know about GUIDs but they are used for unique identifiers and not integers.

Here is where I add a new row knowing that my Primary key is a column named `SheetId`

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   var sheet = db.Sheets.Create();
   sheet.Email = Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["Email"];
   sheet.ApprovedDays = "0000000";
   sheet.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;

   db.Sheets.Add(sheet);

   db.SaveChanges();

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

And this is the Sheet Model

```
public class Sheet
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int SheetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ApprovedDays { get; set; }
    //
    public virtual UserModel UserModel { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Task { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the exception I get

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = SheetId ]

Comment: What does the `Sheet` model look like for the `SheetId` column?

Comment: Probably db.Sheets.Create() will assign a value to SheetId but the database excepts to be empty so it can be autogenerated.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: I've added the Sheet Model

Comment: @juhan_h : after db.Sheets.Create() the value of SheetId is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the Issue by only deleting my .EDMX Context file and Recreated it again and voilà it worked  !! 
Thanks also for your efforts guys

Answer (score 1):

You could try [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] on the key like this :

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int SheetId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove [Required] on the key;

```
[Key]
public int SheetId { get; set; }
```

Comment: The same Exception still exists

Comment: @Osama Which SQL CE version?